# Javascript Iterating Over a Multiselect Dropdown and pushing data into a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to work with this javascript code which gets HTML elements by their name and iterate over the array of them and pushing each into a JSON object. When I run this and print on the console (console.log()) the values array gets populated correctly but the data pushed into JSON is a repetition of one element. What I mean is it looks like this; What am I doing wrong?

```
4: {key: "Cars1", value: "march"}
5: {key: "Cars1", value: "march"}



else if (this.name == "cars") {
    var values = $("#carsID").val();
    $.each(values, function (index, value) {
    jsonData["key"] = "Cars";
    jsonData["value"] = value;
    postData.RowInfo.push(jsonData);
});
```

Comment: `jsonData` has the same key (`Cars`) so the value will always be overwritten. What are the first two lines? That's not valid json...

Comment: in my opinion (to be honest, I'm not sure exactly what the problem is), as pew007 said, it seems to be overwritten by constantly assigning values to the same key value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that jsonData is declared outside this code block and doesn't get created for each element in the values array.

The corrected code;

```
else if (this.name == "cars") {
  var values = $("#carsID").val();
  $.each(values, function (index, value) {
  var jsonDataEach = {};
  jsonDataEach["key"] = "Cars";
  jsonDataEach["value"] = value;
                                            
  postData.RowInfo.push(jsonDataEach);                                          
});
```